# mmap an address very unlikely to be used by any other part of the program

Tags: c, linux, gcc, x86-64

For some reason, I want to allocate a block of memory with `mmap` using a fixed address, that is, with `MAP_FIXED`. So I want to use an address which is very unlikely to be used by any other part of the program (heap, stack etc). Any such address range that will work for a 64 bit system?

Comment: Any that is not in use will do really just make sure to allocate it at program start. Also any reason for `MAP_FIXED`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux will attempt to load ELF executables at the address specified in the executable, which could be ANYWHERE in the 64-bit address space.  Unless you give your linker special options, however, it will build executables that load at low addresses (generally `0x0000000000400000`), and use memory reasonable densely (there will be gaps between read-only and read-write sections), with the default heap coming immediately afterwards.

Linux generally uses addresses in the range `0x00007fff00000000`-`0x00007fffffffffff` for the stack and `0x00007f0000000000`-`0x00007ffeffffffff` for shared libraries.  It also reserves `0x8000000000000000`-`0xffffffffffffffff` for the kernel.

So that means that everything below `0x00007f0000000000` and above the end of the heap is likely to be free, as is the range `0x0000800000000000`-`0x7fffffffffffffff`.  I say likely, because the allocations above are all defaults that are changeable if you configure you kernel or linker to be different.

Comment: Avoid the 0x0000800000000000-0x7fffffffffffffff range. These are not valid on the first (and as far as I know, all to this date) x86-64 processors, which only use 48 bit virtual addresses, with sign extension to fill the other 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

You can mmap into a region that you malloc.  This will make sure that the region of memory is not in use.  Otherwise, you'll either get a segfault or overwrite stuff that is used by the program, because I'm sure the Program Image has very few holes actually.

Comment: No that is not what I want. I want to have an address that I know beforehand, which I can use to mmap, and not some address which is only known at runtime, as in the case of malloc.

Comment: You can't: it doesn't exist really.  Your Program Image will have a little bit a stack/heap space, but nothing like the chunk you're talking about.  stack/heap randomization will make what you're trying impossible, unless you try and stick a payload in there that you know will execute on the cpu.

Comment: @Magn3s1um You have 2^64 addresses you can use since it's virtual, of course it's possible just not reasonable to attempt to do so. You can probably just choose an arbitrarily high address as virtual addresses don't matter but because of VASR you cant guarantee it will always work.

Comment: @Magn3s1um: Wrong. You can do it using mmap. See MAP_FIXED in the documentation for mmap.

Comment: MAP_FIXED only works if you have those pages.  Unless you malloc over already existing pages, MAP_FIXED will fail.  He's worried about overwriting certain things and wants an unused piece of memory.  There won't be an unused piece of memory (besides internal fragmentation between blocks), and there's a fantastic chance he'll either overwrite something important or write more data than he has available in his pages. So no, he can't just use any address he wants, even with MAP_FIXED.  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html